# Read Json file and extract data MAP type

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

could you please help me to extract the container column from JSON file using PYSPARK?

```
df=spark.read.option("inferSchema", 'true').json('/mnt/raw/data/STME/IMS/Location/Year=2023/Month-01/Day=11/data_2023-01-11T10:47:39.8699145Z.json')
```

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql. functions import *
#Create schema for JSON
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType schema StructType([
StructField("containerType", StringType(), True),
StructField("containerId", Integer Type(), True),
StructField("category", StringType(), True),
StructField("containerNumber", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("category", StringType(), True),
StructField("sectionNumber", Integer Type(), True),
StructField("sectionId", Integer Type(), True),
])

df1 = df.withColumn ("containers", from_json(col ("containers"),schema)) df1.printSchema()
df2=df.select(col('addressId'), col('addressName'), col('addressNumber'), col('store'), col('zoneName'))
```

[image]

I tried it

Comment: Edit the question to post the content of the image as code instead.

Answer (score 0):

- I have a similar dataframe as shown in the below image:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.option("inferSchema",True).option("header",True).csv("/FileStore/sample1.csv",quote="'")
display(df)
```

[image]

- Now to convert this string column into map type, you can use the code similar to the one shown below:

```
df.withColumn("value",from_json(df['container'],ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType())))).show(truncate=False)
```

[image]